# Как в запросе отобразить данные объектного типа в табличном виде?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Выполняется следующее:

```
create type del_t_quest is object (v1 varchar2(1000), v2 varchar2(1000));

create table del_quest
(
  id integer  generated always as identity,
  q del_t_quest
);

insert into del_quest
(q)
values
(del_t_quest('aaa','qqq'));
commit;

select id, (select * from table(w.q)) from del_quest w;
```

> ORA-22905: невозможно получить доступ к строкам элемента, не являющегося вложенной таблицей

Как в SQL запросе отобразить такие данные? И в чем причина ошибки?

Comment: select потенциально может возвращать более 1 строки, написав select * from table(...) вы явно ожидаете получить несколько строк, чего в принципе не может быть, когда это используется в виде подзапроса в списке выборки, который по определению не имеет права вернуть более одной строки. Кроме того один параметр в списке выборки может вернуть значение только одной колонки, подзапрос, возвращающий потенциально несколько колонок так же не допустим. думаю `select id, w.q.v1, w.q.v2 from del_quest w` вполне справится с задачей

Comment: Спасибо, Mike  .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> И в чем причина ошибки?

Причина ошибки -- в выражении `table(w.q)` табличный оператор принимает как аргумент тип данных не являющийся вложенной таблицей (см. PS).

> как в sql запросе отобразить данные?

Данные будут отображены, а в каком виде, зависит полностью от клиента, который их отображает. Например, в SQL*Plus так:

```sql
SQL> select q from del_quest w;

Q(V1, V2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DEL_T_QUEST('aaa', 'qqq')
DEL_T_QUEST('aaa', 'qqq')
```

---

В вопросе, по видимому, спрашивается -- как обратитьса к атрибутам колонки объявленой с объектным типом данных.

Как сказано в офф. док. [B.6.1 Qualifying References to Attributes and Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-4E9FC578-F161-454E-BE4B-DE2AC43277CE):

> To reference an attribute or method of a table element, you **must give the table an alias and use the alias** to qualify the reference to the attribute or method.

Только с указанием алиаса таблицы в квалифицированом имени, т.е. так: `table_alias.column_name.attribute`:

```sql
select w.q.v1, w.q.v2 from del_quest w;

Q.V1       Q.V2      
---------- ----------
aaa        qqq
```

---

PS Запрос с ошибкой ORA-22905 из вопроса можно переписать так:

```sql
create or replace type del_t_quests is table of del_t_quest;
/
select t.* 
from (
    select cast (multiset (
            select w.q from del_quest w
        ) as del_t_quests) nt from dual) q
cross join table (q.nt) t;    

V1         V2        
---------- ----------
aaa        qqq
```

Answer (score 4):

Другой подход к решению задачи -- откажитесь от указания колонок реляционной таблицы.
Создайте объектную таблицу [TABLE OF (см. диаграму синтаксиса *object_table*)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6).
Тогда колонками таблицы будут атрибуты объектного типа.
Определите функцию свою `print()`, которая отобразит колонки так, как это требуется.

Например, вот так:

```sql
create or replace type del_t_quest is object (
    id number, v1 varchar2 (1000), v2 varchar2 (1000),
    constructor function del_t_quest (v1 varchar2, v2 varchar2) return self as result,
    member function print (delimiter varchar2 default ' ') return varchar2
);
/
create sequence del_seq_quest nocycle nocache; 
create or replace type body del_t_quest as 
    constructor function del_t_quest (v1 varchar2, v2 varchar2) return self as result is
    begin 
        self.id := del_seq_quest.nextval;
        self.v1 := v1;
        self.v2 := v2;
        return;
    end;
    member function print (delimiter varchar2 default ' ') return varchar2 is
    begin 
        return '['||self.id||'] '||self.v1||delimiter||self.v2;
    end;
end;
/
create table del_quest of del_t_quest (id primary key);
/
insert into del_quest 
    select del_t_quest ('aaa','bbb') from dual;
```

Тогда данные отобразятся так:

```
select q.*, q.print (',') q 
from del_quest q;

        ID V1         V2         Q               
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------------
         1 aaa        bbb        [1] aaa,bbb
```

Comment: необычный подход - круто!